# Change modalPresentationStyle on iOS13 on all UIViewController instances at once using method swizzling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios13

**[Q&A] *Is it possible to change `UIViewController.modalPresentationStyle` value globally on iOS 13 so it behaves like it used to on iOS 12 (or earlier)?***

---

Why?

In iOS 13 SDK the default value of `UIViewController.modalPresentationStyle` property has been changed from `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` to `UIModalPresentationAutomatic` which is, as far as I know, resolved to `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` on iOS devices or at least on iPhones.

Since the project I've been working for several years has become quite big, there are tens of places where a view controller is presented. The new presentation style doesn't always match our app designs and sometimes it causes the UI to fall apart. Which is why, we deciced to change `UIViewController.modalPresentationStyle` back to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` as it was is pre-iOS13 SDK's versions.

But adding `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen` before calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` in every single place where a controller is presented seemed like an overkill. Moreover, we had more serious matters to deal with at that time, which is why, for the time being or at least until we update our designs and fix all the UI issues, we decided to go with method swizzling approach.

**The working solution is presented in my answer, but I would appreciate any feedback telling me what downsides or consequences of such an approach might be.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Here's how we achieved that by using method swizzling:**

---

**Objective-C**

***UIViewController+iOS13Fixes.h***

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIViewController (iOS13Fixes)
@end
```

***UIViewController+ iOS13Fixes.m***

```c
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (iOS13Fixes)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];
        SEL originalSelector = @selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swizzled_presentViewController:animated:completion:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL methodExists = !class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (methodExists) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        } else {
            class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        }
    });
}

- (void)swizzled_presentViewController:(nonnull UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)())completion {

    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        if (viewController.modalPresentationStyle == UIModalPresentationAutomatic || viewController.modalPresentationStyle == UIModalPresentationPageSheet) {
            viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        }
    }

    [self swizzled_presentViewController:viewController animated:animated completion:completion];
}

@end
```

---

**Swift**

***UIViewController+iOS13Fixes.swift***

```swift
import UIKit

@objc public extension UIViewController {

    private func swizzled_present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle == .automatic || viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle == .pageSheet {
                viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            }
        }

        self.swizzled_present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

    @nonobjc private static let _swizzlePresentationStyle: Void = {
        let instance: UIViewController = UIViewController()
        let aClass: AnyClass! = object_getClass(instance)

        let originalSelector = #selector(UIViewController.present(_:animated:completion:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIViewController.swizzled_present(_:animated:completion:))

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, swizzledSelector)

        if let originalMethod = originalMethod, let swizzledMethod = swizzledMethod {
            if !class_addMethod(aClass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod)) {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            } else {
                class_replaceMethod(aClass, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
            }
        }
    }()

    @objc static func swizzlePresentationStyle() {
        _ = self._swizzlePresentationStyle
    }
}
```

and in `AppDelegate`, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` invoke the swizzling by calling (swift version only):

```swift
UIViewController.swizzlePresentationStyle()
```

Make sure it's called only once (use `dispatch_once` or some equivalent).

---

More on method swizzling here:

- https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/
- https://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/
- https://medium.com/rocknnull/ios-to-swizzle-or-not-to-swizzle-f8b0ed4a1ce6

Comment: One problem would be running on an iPad where you actually do want a page sheet and not full screen. You might want to update your check to only change automatic to full screen and only do it when the presenting view controller has compact width traits.

Comment: Is this solution good? What if someone really want to present a ViewController as .pageSheet?

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz then you set `viewController.modalPresentationStyle` to `.pageSheet` and call `self.swizzled_present(:,:,:)`. Maybe it's not very pretty, but the whole point of this post was based on the assumption that you already have an extisting project with lots of calls for modal presentation and you want to restore pre-iOS13 behaviour without updating each line of code.